# Is there a simple example of move construction that won't get elided?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to learn move semantics well enough to introduce it to my students. I've been using highly simplified vector- or string-like classes that manage memory and whose members output messages to demonstrate their activity. I'm trying to develop a simple set of examples to show students.

Construction elision for RVO and elsewhere in gcc 4.7 and clang aggressively eliminates  copy and move construction, so while I can easily see move assignment at work, the only time I've seen move construction at work is if I turn off construction elision in gcc 4.7 with -fno-elide-constructors.

An explicit copy construction statement

```
MyString newString(oldString);
```

will invoke the copy constructor even if elision is enabled. But something like

```
MyString newString(oldString1 + oldString2);
```

doesn't invoke the move constructor because of the elision.

Anything explicitly using std::move won't make a simple example because explaining std::move has to come later.

So my question: Is there a simple code example that will invoke move construction even if copy/move constructors are being elided?

Comment: I'm not certain it can be done without `std::move`...

Comment: "*Anything explicitly using std::move won't make a simple example because explaining std::move has to come later.*" Um, why? `std::move` is *how you move things explicitly*. Move support is primarily about *explicit* moves, since most implicit moves can be caught with elision. You're doing anyone who's learning from this a disservice by hiding `move` from them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: because there are implicit moves, at least in theory.  Think of OP asking for an intermediate level of optimization: `oldString1+oldString2` triggers a copy (no optimization here), but the copy is moved into `newString` (optimization).  In practice, this is hard to trigger because the compiler chooses the "copy elision" optimization over the "move the copy" optimization (with good reason).

Comment: I will have to explain std::move, but it would help if I could demonstrate move construction without having to first introduce std::move (whose explanation is a tad tricky).

Comment: @NicolBolas - sorry, I should have prefixed my comment above to show my comment was in response to yours.

Comment: You could use static_cast instead of move, at least for initial explanations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple example would be an argument to a function that is returned. The standard explicitly forbids eliding the move in this case (not that they could...):

```
std::vector<int> multiply( std::vector<int> input, int value ) {
   for (auto& i : input )
      i *= value;
   return input;
}
```

Additionally, you can explicitly request move construction for an even simpler although a bit more artificial example:

```
T a;
T b( std::move(a) );
```

Uhm... yet another that does not involve `std::move` (it can technically be elided, but most compilers will probably not):

```
std::vector<int> create( bool large ) {
   std::vector<int> v1 = f();
   std::vector<int> v2 = v1;       // modify both v1 and v2 somehow
   v2.resize( v2.size()/2 );
   if ( large ) {
      return v1;
   } else {
      return v2;
   }
}
```

While the optimizer can elide it by rewriting the code as:

```
std::vector<int> create( bool large ) {
   if ( large ) {
      std::vector<int> v1 = f();
      std::vector<int> v2 = v1;       // modify both v1 and v2 somehow
      v2.resize( v2.size()/2 );
      return v1;
   } else {
      std::vector<int> v1 = f();
      std::vector<int> v2 = v1;       // modify both v1 and v2 somehow
      v2.resize( v2.size()/2 );
      return v2;
   }
}
```

I pretty much doubt that the compiler will actually do it. Note that in each code path the object being returned in known before `v1` and `v2` are created, so the optimizer can locate the proper object in the return location after the rewrite.

The situations where copy/move can be elided are described in 12.8/31. If you manage to write code that does not fall into those categories and the type has a move constructor, the move constructor will be called.

Comment: Is this limitation in place because otherwise, implementations could attempt to elide both the argument and the return value?

Comment: @AndréCaron: Copy elision works by reusing the same memory for both the source and the destination objects. For example in `T a = f();` the compiler can locate the `a` object in the same location that the returned value from `f()`. The problem is that the calling convention usually determines the location of both the argument and the returned object, so the compiler cannot force them to be in the same place. More on copy elision [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-nrvo.html) and [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html)

Comment: Yes, the argument and the return value could be in the same place (at least in some cases).  Think of `int f(int x){return x;}` and aggressive inlining.  In the example you presented, you can't elide both the argument copy construction and the return value because you need to construct at least one new object to hold the function's results.  My question is why is this a general limitation?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I'm confused.  Now that I look at your example again, I can't imagine why can't the `input` argument be the return value itself (other than for practical compiler implementations).  Why does the standard forbid it?

Comment: @AndréCaron: Because the standard says so. Because there has to be at least *one* copy, since the function is taking a parameter by value and returning a value by value. So either a copy constructor or a move constructor *must* be called.

Comment: @AndréCaron: Note that with aggressive inlining the compiler can remove the whole function and still behave *as-if* in the same way that any variable can be optimized out if the compiler manages to do so, but in a separate compilation model where the function might not even be seen the copy cannot be elided. In general the calling conventions require that the caller reserves space for the returned object and pass a hidden pointer to the function. For arguments, the caller does the copy to a known location. In a separate compilation, the caller cannot know that the argument is returned [...]

Comment: "For arguments, the caller must perform the copy to a known location...": what's to prevent you from reserving space on the stack and then pushing the previous stack pointer value onto the stack?  (note that this still requires a copy or move of the original vector to initialize the argument but your technical explanation does not apply).

Comment: [...] and even if it knew, the callee does not know that the copy must not be performed (i.e. it does not know that at the call site the argument and the returned object are the same other than by checking the addresses --which would require the test to be done in all calls to the function for an improvement in rare occasions. Additionally, the calling convention usually requires a concrete location for the argument, which would force the location of the variable to a particular address (usually in the stack).

Comment: @AndréCaron: There are very few cases where the call *could* potentially be optimized, and many more where it cannot. The main limitation is that in a separate compilation model the caller and callee would have to agree on whether the copy can be optimized, but because they are in separate translation units the compiler does not know. As I said, if that limitation is removed, the function can be inlined and the compiler can do anything it pleases.

Comment: @AndréCaron: *what's to prevent you from reserving space on the stack and then pushing the previous stack pointer value onto the stack?* This assumes that you can even modify the stack pointer so that this argument is in the right location and at the same time the rest of the arguments are where they should be.

Comment: OK, so if the compiler happens to inline the function (as [hypothesized in this snippet](https://gist.github.com/3640062)), then it might be possible to bypass this limitation.  But in the general case (e.g. the compiler is not inlining the function for a specific call site), this optimization is not possible.  I see!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thanks - that's the kind of simple example that I need; your blog entries on elision are very helpful. It looks like elision is the "normal" case here, so it really has to be part of the story when teaching about move semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, let's see:

- `MyString newString(oldString)` **is** a copy. There's nothing to elide here; we really end up with *two* objects.
- `MyString newString(oldString1 + oldString2);` copies from a temporary, so the copy can be elided and the concatenation is constructed directly in-place.

Here's a really terribly cheap example of un-elidable move construction:

```
MyString boo()
{
    MyString s("Hello");
    return std::move(s);   // move-construction from the local "s", never elided
}
```

The explicit cast makes `s` ineligible for RVO, so the return value will be move-constructed from `s`.